# How to route API Requests through a specific IP?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, networking, ip-address

I am making an iOS and Android App. We require Recharge Functionality in the app. We are planning on using a Recharge API provided by a company.

Due to security reasons the API allows request only through specific IP  whitelisted IP addresses.

This IP address should ideally be the IP of our server.

But we are using Firebase as the database and storage and authentication in our app.

So how can we make such that the API requests made through the App by our users will go through and not cause an error as the user's IP address won't be whitelisted ?

Comment: You will need to proxy the request coming from your app to the recharge API. You shouldn't call the API directly from your app, but rather through a proxy with a whitelisted IP address. Depending on the nature of the API, you can use a ready made solution like NGINX or HAProxy, or write a custom server using any language of your choice

Comment: Can you send me some reference links telling how to do this ?

Comment: You will need a server with a public IP address. You can get one from DigitalOcean, Linode, or Vultr, and install HAProxy. If you can manage Linux, I can guide how to do this using HAProxy in the answer section.

Comment: Yes I can manage Linux and I know how to get deploy a server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to proxy API requests from your users, such that, to your API provider all requests appear to originate from the same static IP address which will be whitelisted.

A proxy is a passive software component that essentially receives requests on one end, and forwards them to the API server on the other end. In other words, it makes API calls on behalf of your users.

You can use NGINX, HAProxy or just any available reverse proxy, or write a custom one using a language of your choice - since it is not a difficult assignment.

Here, is how to set up a reverse proxy using HAProxy on a linux box.

First, install `haproxy` from a linux terminal

`apt update && apt install haproxy`

Then navigate to folder `/etc/haproxy`

`cd /etc/haproxy`

Rename the default configuration file to `haproxy.cfg.backup`

`mv haproxy.cfg{,.backup}`

Now, create a new configuration file, `haproxy.cfg`

`nano haproxy.cfg`

With the following content, and then save changes.

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000

frontend api_proxy
    bind *:8080
    mode http
    default_backend remote_api_server

backend remote_api_server
    #replace 10.10.10.10 with the actual Ip address
    server server1 10.10.10.10:443 ssl
```

Replace `10.10.10.10` with API provider IP address and 443 with the actual port.

If the API is not using HTTPS, remove the `ssl` option

`8080` is the port your users will be connecting to. Change to whatever you want.

Now, start haproxy using the command below:

`haproxy -D -f haproxy.cfg`

You can verify that haproxy is listening on port `8080`

`telnet localhost 8080`

Configure your app to call the recharge API through the proxy URL, which will be:

http://your_server_ip_address:8080/your/api/url

Your will need to configure HTTPS in production environment though.

Check the link below on how to config SSL with haproxy

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTPQH_1.0.0/com.ibm.cloudant.local.install.doc/topics/configure_haproxy.html

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I’ll try this.

Comment: You are welcome. Let me know if you a gonna need any help

Comment: I provisioned a Ubuntu instance from google compute engine. SSH'd into my ubuntu server and did all the configurations that you wrote. Soo. This is my API Link to retrieve values. http://joloapi.com/api/findoperator.php?userid=username&key=0000000000000&mob=9999999999&type=json And say 25.25.199.190 is my IP address of the server on Google Compute Engine. How do i create the proxy url through these values ?

Comment: replace the last line with `server server1 joloapi.com:80`

Comment: In your API, replace `http://joloapi.com/` part with `http://25.25.199.190:8080/`. The rest of the API url remains the same

Comment: Okay. So in the answer where you said replace 10.10.10.10 with the api provider ip. It means the IP address of joloapi.com ? Or the IP address of my virtual machine in compute engine ?

Comment: That should be the  IP address of joloapi.com. You can also use the domain joloapi.com instead of the IP address. It should work

Comment: `joloapi.com` IP address is `54.169.219.19`

Comment: how do we use nginx for the purpose @bentesha

Answer (score 1):

Deploy a server of your choice could be Ubuntu or Windows with your choice of language that could route your requests to the required 3rd party API.

So ideally, all requests from your client will be sent to your server and then your server will resolve the request to the 3rd party and respond back to your clients.

You can look at an example NodeJS/Express REST implementation that can be extended for your required use-case.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

Answer (score 1):

This is bread and butter for nginx.

A location block like this will proxy requests to an upstream;

```
    location / {
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_pass_header       Server;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host upstream-host.com.au;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout   5;
        proxy_read_timeout      240;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;

        proxy_pass      upstream-host.com.au:443;
    }
```

This works beautifully for me. Really easy to set up and I found HAProxy a little finicky in the config where as this is very much easier.